# Pairing Error on Android Messages

Tags: android, message

When I am visiting Android web messages https://messages.android.com/ it gives me Pairing Error. After clicking on OK button same error message comes again. Any idea how to solve this Pairing Error?

FYI: This is a new feature for Android Messages to send text message from Web. Same feature is available on WhatsApp

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue; it was caused by a rogue Chrome extension. Try disabling some of your extensions. Mine was caused by an extension called "Referer Control". It was also preventing me from sending Hangouts messages.

Comment: Have no extension installed on FireFox, still getting this error.

Comment: Fix here: https://community.brave.com/t/messages-android-website-problem/26501/4